# Automation KeyError using Search Cursor / Data Dictionary

Tags: arcpy, cursor, dictionary

I recently received help in modifying a previous code for structures as part of project.  The first time I ran it the code worked fine, but when I went to double check it. I keep receiving:

---

> Runtime error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "string", line 36, in "module"
>
> KeyError: 2

---

Line 36 in the code reads:

```
if valueDictOfficialPipes[2] != ("null" or " "):
```

---

Could anyone please help me in understanding how and why this is occuring.  The table I am using one that has been joined so I am attempt to have it read through 2 columns for both the Collection Company and the Date while ignoring  values and whitespace(" ").  I am not sure if the cursor is registering the the second column.

```
import arcpy as ARCPY
from arcpy import env as ENV
#**TEST ENV**
workspaceTEST = r"C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\TESTSTRM_SWR.gdb"
ENV.workspace = workspaceTEST
#Variables
#=========
#**TEST**
pipes15096 = workspaceTEST + "\PIPES_15096"
pipesOfficial = workspaceTEST + "\OFFICIAL_PIPES2015"
fieldsPipesOfficial = ["ID_NUMBER","DATE_","COMPANY","COLLECTION","COLLECTED_"]
#                         ID        DATE_L1   BY_L1     DATE_L2       BY_L2
# The table is a join between two tables, but I do not have access originals     
#L1 = Table 1 ; L2 = Table 2 
#====================================================
#CURSOR CREATION AND UTILIZATION
#===============================
# Used list comprehension to build a dictionary from a data access SearchCursor  
valueDictOfficialPipes = {readRow4[0]:(readRow4[1:]) for readRow4 in ARCPY.da.SearchCursor(pipesOfficial, fieldsPipesOfficial)}
fieldsPipes15096 = ["ID"  , "COLLECTION_DATE" , "COLLECTED_BY"]
with ARCPY.da.UpdateCursor(pipes15096, fieldsPipes15096) as updateRows_Pipes15096:  
    for updateRow2 in updateRows_Pipes15096:  
        # store the Join value of the row being updated in a keyValue1 variable  
        keyValue2 = updateRow2[0]
        # verify that the keyValue1 is in the Dictionary  
        print "keyValue2:             ", keyValue2
        print "updateRow2:            ", updateRow2        
        if keyValue2 in valueDictOfficialPipes:  
            print "keyValue2 -V2:         ", keyValue2
        # transfer the values stored under the keyValue from the dictionary to the updated fields.  

        # IF BY_L1:"COMPANY" COLUMNS HOLDs VALUE UPDATE CELL            
            if valueDictOfficialPipes[2] != ("<null>" or " "):
                for nullNoMore in range (1,len(fieldsPipes15096)): 
                    updateRow2[nullNoMore] = valueDictOfficialPipes[keyValue2][nullNoMore-1]  
                    print "updateRow2[nullNoMore]:  ",updateRow2[nullNoMore]
            # IF BY_L2:"COLLECT_" COLUMNS HOLD VALUE UPDATE CELL
            elif valueDictOfficialPipes[4] != ("<null>" or " "):
                for nullNoMore in range (1,len(fieldsPipes15096)): 
                    updateRow2[nullNoMore] = valueDictOfficialPipes[keyValue2][nullNoMore-1]  
                    print "updateRow2[nullNoMore]:  ",updateRow2[nullNoMore]

            # IF DATE 1:"COLLECTION" COLUMNS HOLDs VALUE UPDATE CELL            
            if valueDictOfficialPipes[1] != ("<null>" or " "):
                for nullNoMore in range (1,len(fieldsPipes15096)): 
                    updateRow2[nullNoMore] = valueDictOfficialPipes[keyValue2][nullNoMore-1]  
                    print "updateRow2[nullNoMore]:  ",updateRow2[nullNoMore]
            # IF DATE 2:"COLLECTION" COLUMNS HOLD VALUE UPDATE CELL
            elif valueDictOfficialPipes[3] != ("<null>" or " "):
                for nullNoMore in range (1,len(fieldsPipes15096)): 
                    updateRow2[nullNoMore] = valueDictOfficialPipes[keyValue2][nullNoMore-1]  
                    print "updateRow2[nullNoMore]:  ",updateRow2[nullNoMore]
            #UPDATE VALUES IN THE TABLE
            updateRows_Pipes15096.updateRow(updateRow2)
            print "updateRow2:  ",updateRow2
del valueDictOfficialPipes
```

Comment: I think this will be a pure Python problem that should be researched at [so].  To see that try `print valueDictOfficialPipes[2]` on the line before the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to be aware of the data type you are working with!

`valueDictOfficialPipes` is a dictionary.

You are receiving a key error because you are attempting to access the item in `valueDictOfficialPipes` with the key of 2 which doesn't exist.